# ProjNet error in converted coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, convert

today I discovered this library, but after trying to convert coordinates from one to other system find out that there is some calculation error.

I googled possible solutions for this problem, but without success. I found this link and followed instructions but it doesn't work to me.

https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/the-google-maps-bing-maps-spherical-mercator-projection/

I would like to convert coordinate from this zone:
MGI / Balkans zone 6...

to google earth system...

I created this function for testing:

```
        public static void Check(double  x, double y)
    {
        ICoordinateSystem CoordSystemInput = ProjNet.UnitTests.SRIDReader.GetCSbyID(31276);
        var _testCoordinationSystemInput = CoordinateSystemWktReader.Parse(CoordSystemInput.WKT) as IProjectedCoordinateSystem;

        ICoordinateSystem CoordSystemOutput = ProjNet.UnitTests.SRIDReader.GetCSbyID(32767);
        var _testCoordinationSystemOutput = CoordinateSystemWktReader.Parse(CoordSystemOutput.WKT) as IProjectedCoordinateSystem;

        ICoordinateTransformation trans = new CoordinateTransformationFactory().CreateFromCoordinateSystems(_testCoordinationSystemInput, _testCoordinationSystemOutput);

        double[] fromPoint = { x, y };
        double[] p1 = trans.MathTransform.Transform(fromPoint);

        string Lat = p1[0].ToString();
        string Lon = p1[1].ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(Lat.ToString() + "," + Lon.ToString());
    }
```

First one system under number 31276 is:

```
PROJCS["MGI / Balkans zone 6",GEOGCS["MGI",DATUM["Militar_Geographische_Institute",SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6312"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4312"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",18],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999],PARAMETER["false_easting",6500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","31276"]]
```

Second one is under number 32767 is:

```
PROJCS["Popular Visualisation CRS / Mercator",GEOGCS["Popular Visualisation CRS",DATUM["WGS84",SPHEROID["WGS84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7059"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6055"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0, AUTHORITY["EPSG", "8901"]],UNIT["degree", 0.0174532925199433, AUTHORITY["EPSG", "9102"]],AXIS["E", EAST], AXIS["N", NORTH], AUTHORITY["EPSG","4055"]],PROJECTION["Mercator"],PARAMETER["semi_minor",6378137],PARAMETER["False_Easting", 0],PARAMETER["False_Northing", 0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian", 0],PARAMETER["Latitude_of_origin", 0],UNIT["metre", 1, AUTHORITY["EPSG", "9001"]],AXIS["East", EAST], AXIS["North", NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3785"]]
```

Here are my testing coordinates and link on correct result:

```
x = 6503462.895
y = 4922042.835
```

https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=3908&t_srs=900913&x=6503462.8950000&y=4922042.8350000

```
x = 2008028.9823
y = 5534233.6783
```

But this is what I getting (with mistake):

```
x = 2008594.2781
y = 5534328.1856
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

With this example I solved my problem:

https://gist.github.com/erycson/98fe8ab66d168e643621